# If $a(x)$ is eventually strictly greater than $|b(x)|$, does that imply it would be the case for $b(x)$ as well?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I came across a statement and I wonder how to prove it, if $a(x)>|b(x)|$ at some point $N$ as $x$ goes to infinity, then would it also mean it would be strictly greater for $a(x)>b(x)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $|b(x)|\geq b(x)$ for all (not just eventually all) $x$.